# Solving the differential equation $ y'' = x^2 y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on the differential equation:
$$
\
\frac{d^2 \psi}{dx^2} = x^2 \psi
\
$$
My textbook directly states the solution as:
$$
\
\psi(x) = A e^{-x^2/2} + B e^{x^2/2}
\
$$without any detailed explanation. Can someone elucidate the steps to derive this result?

Comment: Did you try plugging this "solution" into the differential equation?

Comment: Check these links (in order): [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27%3Dx%5E2*y&lang=en) and [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderFunction.html)

Comment: The next approximation of the basis solutions in the WKB theory is $x^{-1/2}\exp(\pm x^2/2)$. This is asymptotically correct for large $x$, at $x=0$ one gets linear functions as approximations.